# Cypher get root node filter by relationship

Tags: neo4j

I am trying to create a cypher statement for finding root nodes `a` from a given node `n` in a hierarchical graph structure, where some nodes are "deactivated", meaning the node itself and all connected relationships have a property `deactivated` with a date as value.

I am able to find the root node when also traversing deactivated nodes:

```
MATCH (a)-[rs:child*]->(n)
WHERE NOT ()-[:child]->(a) AND id(n) = $n_id
RETURN DISTINCT a
```

I imagine I have to somehow unwind the relationships `rs` and filter on `exists(r.deprecated)`.

Another solution would be similar to what is found in the [neo4j developer manual](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/) (v3.4) under "7.1.4. Relationships in depth - *Match with properties on a variable length path*":

```
MATCH p =(charlie:Person)-[* { blocked:false }]-(martin:Person)
```

I was hoping for a solution where instead of having to explicitly define a property `deactivated:false` for all non-deactivated relationships, it would ignore relationships with a nonzero `deactivated` property.

Are any of these solutions possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured it out one possible solution by storing the path and removing paths where the relationship has the attribute `deactivated`:

```
MATCH p = (a)-[:child*]->(n)
WHERE NOT ()-[:child]->(a) 
  AND id(n) = $n_id 
  AND NONE (r in relationships(p) WHERE exists(r.deactivated))
RETURN DISTINCT a
```